# how to change the default shell for the sun grid engine

Tags: sungridengine

The sun grid engine defaults to csh, and you have to put this: `#$ -S /bin/sh` into scripts to avoid it. What global configuration setting would change this default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qconf -sql (to list your queues)
qconf -mq YOUR_QUEUE_NAME

(change shell to /bin/sh)